# Salesforce Community Napili Template URL rewriting

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, community, security, napili

Community user when logged in to the portal, copies the community url (Eg:https://community-url/s/detail/recordid) and tries the url in other browser as a guest user. When he does that it shows him an option to login. This poses a security risk. How can i avoid ids in the community url on the record link. Is something like url rewriting for lightning component napili template will work? Any other alternatives.

Comment: I am unclear on why the login page poses a security risk. The point of the login screen is to protect data behind an authentication wall. However, I am also interested to know whether or not community urls can be rewritten.